# UK visiting visa after refugee claim

Tags: visas, uk, refugees

Before 3 months i crossed to canadian border from the US and ask for asylum then after one week i cancel it and went back to my country with removal order from Canada

I'm now planning to sit for an exam in london

Is there any opportunity to get a visa? And should I mention Canada in my travel history in the application for the UK visa?

Answer (score 4):

You must tell the truth. UK visa applications ask about previous immigration history. The ‘five eyes’ countries (USA, Canada, UK, Australia, and New Zealand) share immigration data.

Just an opinion, but with that record it’s highly unlikely you’d be able to convince a UK ECO that you are a genuine visitor per V4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: I second the opinion. Applying for asylum indicates a strong desire to never return to one's home country, which is the exact opposite of what a UK visa officer is looking for. And the fact that the asker applied for asylum -- i.e., claimed that their life or freedom was in serious danger in their home country -- and then changed their mind a week later will make it hard for a visa officer to trust what they say.